# Collapsible Divs: Want all divs to open when one is clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on a landing page for my employer. In order to put in content for SEO without cluttering the page, we've put some collapsible divs in place.
The only caveat is that we want all of these to open and close simultaneously, not just one at a time.

This is the JS:

```
`$(document).ready(function()   
{
$(".content-body").hide();
$(".contentheader").click(function()
{
$(this).next(".content-body").slideToggle(100);
});
});
```

What modifications would I need to make? Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to set the .content-body class to display:none by default, so you don't see them all closing when you first load the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a class to all divs that you want controlled, and you can use a jQuery selector to pick those.

Example:

`$('.toggleDiv').slideToggle(100);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! All the items have this class on them already ("content-body"). Is it because of the ".next?" I found this code online and modified. I'm still a bit new to this, so thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. This will do what you want and it has an optional easing function which will animate the process.